# Android: Google Fit: Sessions Start/End BroadcastReceivers Not Triggering

Tags: android, session, google-fit

I want to be able to start a BroadcastReceiver when a Google Fit session starts or ends on a phone. I have the manifest set up for the receivers:

```
    <receiver android:name=".YogaSessionStartedBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.fitness.session_start" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.google.fitness.activity_type/yoga" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name=".YogaSessionEndedBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.fitness.session_end" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.google.fitness.activity_type/yoga" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And I'm starting a session with activity type YOGA in my app:

```
    mSession = new Session.Builder()
            .setName(SESSION_NAME)
            .setIdentifier(getString(R.string.app_name) + " " + System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setDescription("Yoga Session Description")
            .setStartTime(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .setActivity(FitnessActivities.YOGA)
            .build();

    PendingResult<Status> pendingResult =
            Fitness.SessionsApi.startSession(mGoogleApiClient, mSession);
```

However onReceive is never called in my BroadcastReceivers. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted. It's a legitimate question and I can't find any answers anywhere about how Google Fit uses broadcast receivers outside of a small snippet of documentation: https://developers.google.com/fit/android/using-sessions#session_start_intents

Comment: Any news on this issue? Google Fit API docs are desperately outdated

Answer (score 1):

Have you Register for Session ?

```
registerForSessions (GoogleApiClient client, PendingIntent intent)
```

Something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,YogaSessionEndedBroadcastReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
Fitness.SessionsApi.registerForSessions(mClient,pendingIntent);
```

Which mClient is your GoogleApiClient,And mContext is your Activity Context.